# php 5.2 - FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS

Tags: php-5.2, filter-var

I am trying to modify my coding styles and am getting used to using `filter_var($input,FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS)`.  I have gotten used to using the other filter_var options with no difficulty.

In this specific case though, `FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS` can only be used in newer versions of php than the one my hosting provider uses.  We are still on php 5.2.17.  My question is, how do I accomplish the same task with the same reliability as using this easy call to the filter_var function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the best of my knowledge, the only solution I could come up with is as follows.  Still not sure if it's functionally identical or not, but my testing has shown it to work much the same....

```
filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP|FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH|FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
```

***NOTE:***
When using more than one `filter_var` flag, you separate each flag *after the first one* with a pipe instead of a comma, or `filter_vars` breaks....  Took a while to figure that one out! :)

Comment: Right, it's a bitwise "or"!

Comment: according to the documentation, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS is "Equivalent to calling htmlspecialchars() with ENT_QUOTES set" - did you try that?